# Steady States and fractional Population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, steady-state

If I'm assuming that I have a population of size $N(t)$ that is growing, can my steady states be fractions? I'm quite confused because how can a population be a fraction? Note that the differential equation is given by 
$\frac{dN}{dt}=H(N)$. Where $H(N)$ is a function of $N$ and the steady states are the values of $N$ such that $H(N)=0$.

Comment: It's only an approximation of the underlying discrete reality. It's not all that different from treating matter as a continuum when in reality it consists of atoms.

Comment: Another explanation could be: $N(t)$ is the *density* of the population at time $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details of what exactly $H(N)$ is it's hard to say whether you are getting fractions from some computational error or whether the steady states really are at fractional values of $N$.  That being said, since differential equation population models are a continuous approximation to a discrete situation, there is the certainly the possibility that the model will predict fractional steady states.  You should treat those results as approximations, not as indicating a fractional number of individuals.

Comment: Okay, if for instance I have a steady state N_s, all I know that dN/dt decreases for values larger than N_s and increases for smaller values, why does this mean that N_s is stable?

Comment: That's essentially what stable means. If you start there and the population fluctuates a bit in either direction it will go back to N_s